# Kivy add widget won't appear on screen:

Tags: python, kivy, grid-layout

I'm stuck with the following problem:

When I run the following code - this seems to work:

```
class Board(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, numLines=8, numCols=8, **kwargs):
        # constructor of the board
        GridLayout._init_(self, **kwargs)
        self.finish_game = Button()
        # Code that operates on the button
        self.finish_game.text = "You lose"
        self.add_widget(self.finish_game)
        # The rest of the code that doesn't matter for now ...

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'based graphics'
        return Board()


TestApp().run()
```

But when I try **this**, I see through debugging mode that it goes inside the Board(), but it doesn't show anything on screen:

```
class StartBoard(Layout):
    def _init_(self):

        Layout._init_(self)
        # Some code that works and not important
        return Board()

class Board(GridLayout): 
  .... #As before

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'based graphics'
        return StartBoard()

TestApp().run()
```

I know it's not a full code, but maybe you could explain how does TestApp().run() works and why would Board() shows widgets when it run from TestApp.build() and not from StartBoard().

Answer (score 1):

Running `Board()` creates an instance of the `Board` class, but that doesn't fundamentally draw anything. It will appear on your screen only if you add it to your widget tree somehow.

In your code you `return Board()`, but that return doesn't go anywhere so the `Board()` is instantiated and immediately discarded.

You probably want something like `self.add_widget(Board())` instead.